# TCP LogStash PHP steam socket working in shell but not file

Tags: php, sockets, logstash

I have a a logstash tcp server running which accepts a tcp socket connection, I can write to that connection on the php shell.

If I use the same code in a file I get the following lines in logstash debug console and nothing goes into my elasticsearch instance

```
[DEBUG] 2020-07-15 10:31:40.987 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] jsonlines - config LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines/@charset = "UTF-8"
[DEBUG] 2020-07-15 10:31:40.987 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] jsonlines - config LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines/@id = "json_lines_dbda8bcd-69ed-4356-81af-381355f76e2f"
[DEBUG] 2020-07-15 10:31:40.987 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] jsonlines - config LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines/@enable_metric = true
[DEBUG] 2020-07-15 10:31:40.987 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3] jsonlines - config LogStash::Codecs::JSONLines/@delimiter = "\n"
```

Logstash config

```
input {
tcp {
 port => 5080
 codec => "json"
 id => "PHP_TCP_LOGS"
 }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]    
      index => "%{[xx]}"
   }
}
```

PHP File

```
$socket = stream_socket_client('tcp://localhost:5080', $errorNumber, $error, 30);

$a = ["foo"=>"barr"];
fwrite($socket, json_encode($a) . "\n");

echo $error;
```

Comment: So the application was terminating before socket data was being written.